# PHP и не Highload приложение

Tags: php

Нужно обосновать выбор PHP для разработки следующего проекта - информационная веб система, в которой будет 30-40 пользователей, одновременно активных штук 7 (то есть работают одновременно штук 7, а авторизированы почти все). Один человек предложил обосновать выбор так "PHP так как пишем не HighLoad приложение". Но почему конкретно PHP "хорош" в разработке не highload приложений? (по идее такая информационная система будет же являться не хайлоад?)

Comment: Мне больше интересно почему PHP НЕ подходит для highload? Если успешно по всему миру их делают на этом языке и проблем нет. ...

Comment: Надо отталкиваться не только от языка, если уж на то пошло. А от ОС, под которую будет писаться, от железок, от требований к производительности к ним, от требования по загрузкам страниц (если такие есть), от требований к приложению в целом, т.к. у некоторых языков могут не оказаться норм библиотек или инструментов для решения проблемы...........Вот например выберите C#. А разрабатывать надо под Astra Linux где оного нет..... и до свиданья....или Postgres 14, которого тоже в той же Астре нет....и т.д........А вот это ваша игра с языком - это мелочь....

Comment: А писать можно на чём угодно. Если штат   состоит в основном из джавистов, а проект надо завтра - то и выбирать PHP нет смысла

Comment: Да не то, что он не подходит под HighLoad, это не важно подходит или нет. Важно почему он подойдёт для не HighLoad. 
Ну и я уже всё, сделал на PHP всё, мне надо по итогу каким-то образом кратко обосновать этот выбор.

Comment: Язык, заточенный конкретно под веб-приложения. Логично, что если у Вас простое приложение, то проще писать на том, где есть много опыта, пакетов, в целом язык простой для такого. Но никто не мешает писать на чем удобнее

Answer (score 0):

1. На PHP у вас есть возможность очень быстро насобирать MVP функционал, абстрагироваться от написания бойлерплейта и сконцентрироваться на доменной логике. Пара фреймворков, которые снизят головную боль и ускорят разработку в разу: Symfony, Laravel. Если взять Symfony, то несравнимый + это Doctrine ORM, такого мало где можно найти с аналогичным кол-вом сахара.
2. Доступность человеческих ресурсов + не сильно высокий порог вхождения. PHP занимает очень крупный процент в WEB-е, соответственно, проблем с кадрами быть не должно и заменить тоже в пределах реального. Так же, данный язык довольно прост для понимания, что позволит нанять более низкоквалифицированного разработчика, но который уже сможет потянуть поддержание и доработку функционала.
3. Нельзя конечно сказать, что на PHP не пишут Highload, т.к. нынче у вас Nginx, FPM, JIT, perloading, асихрон (RebbitMQ/Apach Kafka) и подобные плюшки доступны, т.е., можно потянуть порядочные нагрузки.
   Но в контексте высокой нагрузки, часто требуют скорость отклика в пределах каких-то цифр + держать RPS на постоянном уровне, вот тут, уже есть смысл задуматься.
4. Так же, грех не сказать, что хорошо работает с HTTP протоколом, нативно разбирает данные из запроса в суперглобальные массивы, что облегчает реализацию Rest-a допустим.
5. Куча репозиториев и либ, которые помогут в работе с нетривиальными вещами, собрать ZIP, распарсить Xlsx, обработать и снизить качество видео, интегрироваться с разными платежными системами и т.д, и т.п.

P.S. Пыху очень давно и упорно точат под то, чтоб быстро и качественно собирать более или менее тривиальные дешбоарды и т.д., в таком случае, нужно смотреть на необходимость в дальнейшем поддерживать систему, расширять и дорабатывать на долгом промежутке времени.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137232/discussion-on-answer-by-borislav-php---highload-).